# Why my bootstrap.min.css seems not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

["The text is not moving to right side of the logo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGUxJ.jpg)I am currently doing a web development course from Coursera. There i am stuck in a position of using "pull-left" class of bootstrap. In lecture the "pull-left" bootstrap class had been used to move the name besides the logo. But its not working for me. I removed and tried to use inline-css of float left property and it worked completely fine. I am providing some screenshots. My question is why my pull-left property not working?[[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHgYs.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Special Restrurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navber-header">
                    <a href="index.html" class="pull-left visible-md visible-lg">
                      <div id="logo-img" alt="logo-img"></div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a href="index.html"><h1>Special Restrurant</h1></a>
                         <p> 
                            <img src="images/star-five.jpg" height=45 width=45>
                            <span>ISO Certified</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please paste your code instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: Please share your code in the snippet format. Thank You!!

Comment: why dont u just follow bootstrap 4 doc : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add the "pull-left" class to both elements - anchor tag and 'navbar-brand' div?